# In a running Tmux session, how can find out what configuration file tmux is using?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, tmux

I am on Arch Linux and I am running `tmux` in my terminal.

```
~ ❯ tmux -V
tmux 3.2a
```

When running in a tmux session, how can I find out if:

1. A `tmux.conf` is being used
2. The location of the `tmux.conf` file being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there may be a misunderstanding: when you are "in a tmux session", `tmux.conf` is not "being used", it *has been used*. Compare [this answer about Bash and `.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698166/108618), similar situation. One of the paragraphs of the linked answer can be "translated" from "bash" to "tmux". The "translated" version will be:

Do not treat <strike>`.bashrc`</strike> `tmux.conf` as a file that holds current settings for the <strike>shell</strike> tmux server. It is meant to be sourced *once in a clean <strike>shell</strike> tmux server, automatically*. People sometimes source it again manually and it works* […]

<sup>* It works with possible side effects from executing old things for the second time.</sup>

After parsing a configuration file, tmux server could even forget about the file. At this point the configuration of the server *itself* is what matters. The configuration is imposed by the file, but neither stored in nor updated from the file. Changes in the file cannot affect the already running server because the file (i.e. the old version of it) has already been processed.

Tmux, however, does remember what configuration file(s) have been loaded. This information is available as the format variable named [`config_files`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#config_files). E.g. in a shell inside tmux you can do:

```
tmux display-message -p 'This is a list of config files: #{config_files}'
```

For me the command prints:

```
This is a list of config files: /etc/tmux.conf,/home/kamil/.tmux.conf
```

---

If you really want to know the file *being* used then check the [`current_file`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#current_file) format variable. `#{current_file}` in a format string will expand to the pathname of the file being processed (automatically or with `source-file`). Outside of any file (e.g. if you run `tmux display-message -p '#{current_file}'` in a shell inside tmux) it will expand to an empty string.

According to the [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/3.3a/CHANGES), `current_file` was added in tmux 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Not great, but run with `tmux -v` (starting in a directory where your user has write permissions, then `grep loading tmux-server-<pid>.log`.  Remember to exit and delete the logs since they grow quickly.

In general, however, you should only have a few possibilities for config file locations that are being read (tested on 3.2a):

- First, if `tmux -f configfile` is used, it trumps all others.  Not even the system config will be processed.
- If there's no `-f` on the commandline:

  - then the system `/etc/tmux.conf` is processed, if it exists.
  - then the user config in `~/.tmux.conf` is processed, if it exists.
  - then (3.2a specific) the user config in `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf` is processed, if it exists.

Of course, any of these could `source-file` another, which could `source-file` another, and so on.  But at least it should be fairly easy to unwind what configs are in play.

Comment: When you say `3.2a specific` what do you mean? Are you saying only version 3.2a will look at `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`? Or will all versions greater than 3.2a also check that directory?