# bashrc + why source not refresh the .bashrc file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, rhel, alias

we add the following line to `bashrc` file

```
alias reboot="echo you not allowed to do reboot on this machine - sorry"
```

so we get

```
more ~/.bashrc

# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi


alias reboot="echo you not allowed to do reboot on this machine - sorry"
```

then we did

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and indeed when we do

```
reboot
```

we got

```
you not allowed to do reboot on this machine - sorry
```

but when we want to back to  real reboot , we removed the line -->  `alias reboot="echo you not allowed to do reboot on this machine - sorry"`

as the following:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

and we refresh the bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

but we still get the old alias when we try to reboot:

```
 you not allowed to do reboot on this machine - sorry
```

what we are missing here?

another example with function

```
echo '
function reboot
{
echo "ERROR reboot command not allowed on this machine"
return 1
}
' >>/root/.bashrc
```

with example above we cant to do `unalias`

Comment: `alias reboot="echo you not allowed to do reboot on this machine - sorry"`? Is the really supposed to stop a root user from rebooting the system?  `unalias -a` and then `reboot` still works, or `\reboot`, or `/sbin/reboot` or `init 6` or a bunch of others.  If you don't want someone to have `root` privileges you can't give them access to the `root` account.

Comment: Am I understanding this right? Do you want to _disallow `reboot`_ for the root user? Would it not be better to limit the people who can become root? I mean, it looks as if you are setting up an interactive account for the root user. You might just as well set up a non-privileged account, which would automatically not be allowed to reboot, and then selectively give that account access to different commands with `sudo`.

Comment: reboot its only example , its can be any other command , I accept your suggestion about to limit the using of command by secure or limit root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sourcing `~/.bashrc` does not magically reset all settings. The file is just a bunch of commands to be executed. If they are executed in a clean shell then you will get what you expect.

But if the alias has already been defined, the lack of it in the file will not unalias it. Think about it: if you executed the commands from the file by hand, none would affect the already defined alias. There is no `unalias reboot` in the file. Sourcing `~/.bashrc` is exactly executing the commands, only not "by hand".

Do not treat `.bashrc` as a file that holds current settings for the shell. It is meant to be sourced *once in a clean shell, automatically*. People sometimes source it again manually and it works* if they add something, because the added thing gets executed. A removed thing cannot be executed or magically reverted. Start a new shell and let `.bashrc` do its job in the way it's designed for.

Note it's totally easy to bypass an alias or a function. The alias or the function is not a good way to disallow rebooting.

---

<sup>* It works with possible side effects from executing old things for the second time.</sup>

Comment: unalias isnt relevant for example to function reboot in bashrc , so what is your suggestion if we remove function for reboot ?

Comment: see the update in the Question

Comment: @yael I don't get the point. A function is also not a good way to disallow rebooting. `.bashrc` is meant to be sourced *once in a clean shell, automatically*. People sometimes source it again manually and it works (with possible side effects!) if they *add* something, because the added thing gets executed. A removed thing cannot be executed or magically reverted.

Comment: so what is your suggestion to avoid using reboot command ?  instead of bashrc

Comment: @yael Oh, now the question seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). I may know (or research) an answer, but it will be best if you asked a separate question: "How can I disallow `reboot`?" or similar. In the new question tell us if your user is currently allowed to `reboot` without `sudo`, and the output of `ls -l /sbin/reboot` (or whatever path `reboot` is in your OS).

Comment: @yael yes, please post a new question and clarify exactly what you need and how robust it must be. The alias you describe is trivial to circumvent (just use the full path to the `reboot` command or `command reboot` or `\reboot`; see [How can I run original command that aliased with same name?](https://askubuntu.com/a/525242)), so we need to know more details to give you a good solution.