# tmux continues using variables that are no longer defined in .bashrc

Tags: bash, tmux, debugging

I am trying to reset my `.bashrc`, because it has become bloated and it takes long to start a console.

For this I did the following:

```bash
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

This worked for the normal login bash shell.

But I also use TMUX for terminal multiplexing and it does not seem to update/remove the previously defined environment variables (which no longer exist)... for instance:

I redefined PS1 to output git information. Its definition in my old `.bashrc` was:

```bash
function parse_git_branch {
git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/[\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}
export PS1='\u@\h \[\033[1;33m\]\W\[\033[0m\] \[\e[91m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ '
```

Now that this is no longer defined in `.bashrc`, I get the following error in TMUX, after each command that I execute (when it prints the prompt):

```
-bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

This happens when I start a new TMUX session with:

```bash
tmux new -s TEST
```

Outside of TMUX everything is behaving as expected.

Do I somehow need to reset TMUX separately? What can I do to debug this, because I am completely stuck?!

EDIT:

1. I should note that I am still running older TMUX session that were started before editing my `.bashrc`.
2. Here is the value of `$PS1` in TMUX vs. outside, as "proof" that something is "weird":

Inside TMUX:

```bash
$ echo $PS1
\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\W \[\e[91m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$
-bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

Outside TMUX:

```bash
$ echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

Comment: Environment variables exist inside processes. Removing them from some file does not modify running processes.

Comment: Completely kill and restart your `tmux` server

Comment: ^^^ Ditto. Your changes do not affect the already running tmux server (see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1424154/432690)). When the sever starts a new shell, the old settings remembered by the server affect the new shell (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698166/108618), the shell is not "clean").

Comment: Thanks for the input. I suspected this, which was why I added the edit-comment. At the same time, I was expecting terminals within TMUX to be "separate" bash instances. But they inherit the environment of TMUX server, because they are sub-processes, correct?! So is there is now way around killing and restarting the tmux server? I have some session, that will take effort to restore...

Comment: You can always re-configure your running tmux server "by hand". My first link mentions tmux commands you can use to manipulate the environment. A bunch of carefully crafted [`tmux set-environment …` commands](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#GLOBAL_AND_SESSION_ENVIRONMENT) in a shell inside tmux should do.