# How to add a New Window button to status bar in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I would like to add a button to the status bar/line in tmux, which will create a new window on mouse click (provided that the mouse mode is on). How can I do it?

Comment: `tmux` has (as far as I know) no concept of buttons. You need to code this yourself and compile it. https://github.com/tmux/tmux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clickable buttons have been recently implemented in tmux, see the [example](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3652#issuecomment-1685300798) which opens a new window upon clicking on `[+]` button:

```
set -g window-status-format '#W#{?window_end_flag,#[range=user|new][+]#[norange],}'
bind -Troot MouseDown1Status if -F '#{==:#{mouse_status_range},window}' {
    select-window
} {
    if -F '#{==:#{mouse_status_range},new}' {
        new-window
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following binding will create a new window upon clicking on the unused part of the status line:

```
bind-key -T root MouseDown1StatusDefault new-window
```

It's not exactly a distinct button, but it works well, at least as long as there is the unused part of the status line. If you spawn many, many windows, so every part of the status line is "used", you won't be able to use the binding. For this reason consider an extra binding:

```
bind-key -T root MouseDown1StatusRight new-window
```

See details in the [manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#MOUSE_SUPPORT).

The commands are for `.tmux.conf`. Remember [the file matters when a tmux server starts, not later](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757783/108618). To reconfigure an already running server an easy way is to invoke `tmux bind-key …` in a shell inside tmux.

Comment: That was helpful, Thanks!
How do you know that its ˋMouseDown1ˋ and not ˋMouseDown2ˋ ? What is the difference?

Comment: @AshwinKumark I know because I have tried. My mouse has several buttons and `MouseDown1` refers to one of them, `MouseDown2` refers to *another one* of them, etc.