# How do I fix Tmux status bar?

Tags: tmux, tmux-plugin-manager

I tried a new theme plugin I found from gihub: [tmux-tokyo-night](https://github.com/fabioluciano/tmux-tokyo-night). I didn't like it, so I removed the plugin (confirmed with my .tmux.conf file that it was removed) but the broken status bar won't go away: [image] I tried uninstalling/reinstalling tmux multiple times and I can't seem to fix it. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: (1) "I tried uninstalling/reinstalling tmux" – Have you restarted the tmux server? or the whole OS? (2) "confirmed with my .tmux.conf file that it was removed" – Consider showing us your current `.tmux.conf` file (as text, not as a picture).

Comment: Reload the .tmux.conf config. Press tmux prefix (usually `Ctrl b`), followed by `r`. Also make sure you actually updated the correct tmux config file (`~/.tmux.conf`)

Comment: @GMaster [Reloading may or may not be enough](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757783/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski
"
set -g (at)plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g (at)plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
"
This is currently all I have in my ~/.tmux.conf file. The theme was one line "set -g ..." below line two. I removed that line, ran "Ctrl b Alt u" to complete the uninstall of the theme, and ran the command line "tmux source ~/.tmux.conf". I haven't yet restarted the OS.

Update: I just tried restarting my OS and that fixed it! Thank you everyone!

Comment: What if you start a separate tmux server? (with e.g. `tmux -L arbitrary-name`). Does the problem occur?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the issue persisted in all servers. Restarting the OS fixed it though.

Comment: There is 2 options to solve. First, you need to install proper font (e.g ttf). Or, check the config file which explained above.